# Is HTML5's getUserMedia for audio recording working now?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I had searched a lot of DEMO and examples about getUserMedia , but most are just camera capturing, not microphone.

So I downloaded some examples and tried on my own computer , camera capturing is work ,
But when I changed

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video : true},gotStream);
```

to

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio : true},gotStream);
```

The browser ask me to allow microphone access first, and then it failed at

```
document.getElementById("audio").src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

The message is :

```
GET blob:http%3A//localhost/a5077b7e-097a-4281-b444-8c1d3e327eb4 404 (Not Found)
```

This is my code: [getUserMedia_simple_audio_test](http://pastie.org/3985501)

Did I do something wrong?  Or only getUserMedia  can work for camera now ?

Comment: Even you put [`"video, audio"`, it](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/JV996/) still won't get the `audio` part (if you have noticed.)

Comment: In chrome version 19, 'xxx' work.  But in version 21, only { xxx :true } work, This is what I found after I updated  chrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is currently not available in Google Chrome. See [Issue 112367](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112367).

You can see in [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/JV996/), it will always throw an error saying

> GET blob:http%3A//whatever.it.is/b0058260-9579-419b-b409-18024ef7c6da 404 (Not Found)

And also you can't listen to the microphone either in

```
{
    video: true,
    audio: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks !!   I hope that it will be available in chrome soon.

Answer (score 5):

It is currently supported in Chrome Canary. You need to type about:flags into the address bar then enable Web Audio Input.

The following code connects the audio input to the speakers. WATCH OUT FOR THE FEEDBACK!

```
<script>
// this is to store a reference to the input so we can kill it later 
var liveSource;
// creates an audiocontext and hooks up the audio input
function connectAudioInToSpeakers(){
  var context = new webkitAudioContext();  
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream) {
    console.log("Connected live audio input");
    liveSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    liveSource.connect(context.destination);
  });
 }
// disconnects the audio input
function makeItStop(){
   console.log("killing audio!");
   liveSource.disconnect();
 }
// run this when the page loads
connectAudioInToSpeakers();
</script>
<input type="button" value="please make it stop!" onclick="makeItStop()"/>
```

Comment: i don't think it is...audio playback form microphone yes; (and only in chrome for mac; and chrome canary) but recording? don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

(sorry, I forgot to login, so posting with my proper username...)

It is currently supported in Chrome Canary. You need to type `about:flags` into the address bar then enable Web Audio Input.

The following code connects the audio input to the speakers. WATCH OUT FOR THE FEEDBACK!

http://jsfiddle.net/2mLtM/

```
<script>
// this is to store a reference to the input so we can kill it later 
var liveSource;
// creates an audiocontext and hooks up the audio input
function connectAudioInToSpeakers(){
  var context = new webkitAudioContext();  
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream) {
    console.log("Connected live audio input");
    liveSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    liveSource.connect(context.destination);
  });
 }
// disconnects the audio input
function makeItStop(){
   console.log("killing audio!");
   liveSource.disconnect();
 }
// run this when the page loads
connectAudioInToSpeakers();
</script>
<input type="button" value="please make it stop!" onclick="makeItStop()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working, you just need to add `toString` parameter after `audio : true`

Check this article - [link](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2012/06/introduction-to-getusermedia/)

Comment: The `toString` thing is a hack to support the old parameter format (`"video, audio"`) and the new format (`{video: true, audio: true}`) together. In Chrome, audio hasn't been implemented at all yet, so there is no "trick" to get it suddenly working.