# How to detect sound blowing/screaming using a microphone (for a proof of concept)?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently programming a quick'n'dirty HTML5 prototype for an hackathon.

The user has to blow on his laptop microphone (or scream at it!) until it reaches a certain (arbitrary) level.

I did not find anything that could help me on a tight schedule so far...

Due to the event type (hackathon), I want to achieve something that just Works, it doesn't have to be stable or secure... well, it's a prototype :-)

We use HTML5 and, of course, JavaScript. jQuery is already used in the project, and the demo will be shown using a recent version of Chromium.

I hope I am clear enough, please do not hesitate to ask me for more info if needed.

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is HTML5's getUserMedia for audio recording working now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791457/is-html5s-getusermedia-for-audio-recording-working-now) See also [this introduction](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/). Please come back with a more specific question if you struggle with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the non-stable Web Audio API and `getUserMedia`.

On html5rocks is a short article about that feature:
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Live-Web-Audio-Input-Enabled

Comment: I finally ran some (too many for a hackathon) tests, nothing worked. I mean, we even tried the online demos on many computers, under many OS and browsers, _nothing_. We didn't have the time to investigate more, the final behavior was actually faked during the presentation (but we did not lie about this :D). With a little more hardware, we would have used the Arduino already in place (for the physical part of the project), which would have done the job exactly as needed. Thanks anyway!